# Install Wine 1.5 in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, wine

How do I upgrade to Wine 1.5 on Ubuntu 10.04?

I have tried `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to compile it yourself or you upgrade to Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04 and use the [WineHQ PPA](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

The newest version you can get from the [Wine-PPA for Lucid](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=lucid) is 1.4.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I mean how do I compile iy

Comment: I think the better solution is to upgrade your system because support for Ubuntu 10.04 will end in April 2013.

Comment: If you are not a developer, upgrading is going to be quite easier than compiling, but if you really want to do it, ask another question. The highest wine version available for 10.04 is wine 1.3, if you really need 1.5, you should upgrade.

Comment: @Javier Rivera you are wrong it's 1.4 "wine1.3  1.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1" and I know. I mean he could get Wine 1.5 if he use the PPA in Precise.

Comment: I don't have a Lucid install to test it, but it looks like 1.3 to me (it's the 1.4 version of 1.3 as I read it, or it is some ugly hack to force wine1.3 to upgrade to 1.4). Anyway it doesn't matter, to use 1.5 he should upgrade or learn to compile the hard way (wine is one of the hardest programs to compile as it has tons of dependencies that are only needed at runtime).

Comment: @Javier Rivera if you look in the "VERSION" file in the [wine1.3_1.4.orig.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+files/wine1.3_1.4.orig.tar.gz) archiv, you see "Wine version 1.4".

Comment: You're rigth, a quick look at the source confirms that this is wine1.4. This shouldn't be packaged as wine1.3, it will automatically update people on 1.3 to 1.4 and this is not an expected behaviour.